# Objective-C Json Deserializing (null values cannot be deserialized)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, afnetworking, jsonmodel

I am making http post from iOS to my web service which was written on .NET platform.

I am using [JSONModel](http://www.jsonmodel.com/) to serialize/deserialize and [AFNetworking](http://www.afnetworking.com/) to make http requests.

I can make request and get response successfully. But when any variable on response data is null problem occurs.

Here is how I call my web service:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"Username":username,@"Password":password};
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"<my_url>" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Request succeeded.
    LoginResponse *response =[[LoginResponse alloc]initWithDictionary:responseObject error:nil];
    // !!! "response" is null here because of Message on response data is null.
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Request failed.
}];
```

Here is my `LoginResponse.h` file:

```
@interface LoginResponse : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *IsSuccess;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Message;

@end
```

This is what web service returns when I request via Fiddler:

```
{"IsSuccess":true,"Message":null}
```

Since I have null values on response data, deserialization does not work. When I remove (because Message on response data is null) `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Message;` line from `LoginResponse.h` file, deserialization works fine.

I don't care whether response data has null variable or not, I just want to deserialize it. I can't estimate what the problem is. Why deserialization does not work when response has null variable?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `Message` optional in `LoginResponse`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString<Optional>* Message;
```

See the [JSONModel docs](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/README.md#optional-properties-ie-can-be-missing-or-null) for more info.

Comment: Oops how I have missed it! Thanks.